# firebase phone auth failing with MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to move to firebase auth from digits and I have used Android studio firebase tool to configure firebase settings in my app. I am trying to use firebase auth ui for phone verification.

My code is:

```
authButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startActivityForResult(
                    AuthUI.getInstance()
                            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                            .setAvailableProviders(
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.PHONE_VERIFICATION_PROVIDER).build()
                                    ))
                            .build(),
                    RC_SIGN_IN);

        }
    });
```

Now, when I click on the auth button, I get the phone number input ui and I put in my phone number, but when I click on Verify my phone number...I get a popup saying An internal error has occurred [MISSING_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER].

As requested, my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.id"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 258
    versionName "1.2.40"
}
buildTypes {
    staging {
        applicationIdSuffix ".staging"
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_STAGING", "true"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.configstaging
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.releaseConfig
    }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://urbanairship.bintray.com/android" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
        // quickly to Android tooling updates
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Urban Airship SDK
    // Recommended for in-app messaging
    //    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.2.0'
//    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.11.1@aar') {
//        transitive = true;
//    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'
    compile 'com.urbanairship.android:urbanairship-sdk:8.6.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.9.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:1.4.3'
    compile 'com.rollbar:rollbar-android:0.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.appsee:appsee-android:+'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My onActivityResult is never hit. I tried to debug this.
I am using an actual device not a simulator. I have added the SHA1 too in my firebase project. Has anyone else come across this?

Comment: make sure your sha1 key should be same in googledeveloperconsole as well as firebase console

Comment: @GeetaGupta I can see the SHA key in my firebase console, how the see the SHA in google developer console? I can see the list of service accounts.

Comment: in google developer console, go to Api and Services and then go to credentials and the match your package name and sha key

Comment: @GeetaGupta They are same. Verified just now.

Comment: can you put your complete login auth code along with libraries and manifest

Comment: or try to download updated .json file from firebase console and then try

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: I am using urbanairship too. Can it cause an issue as it gave me a lot of trouble while migrating from digits to firebase in iOS

Comment: for ios no idea,

Comment: I resolved iOS problem. I thought android would not have the same issue.

Comment: did you solve this issue on android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally solved this problem, it's very frustrating that firebase doesn't document such a common issue.

Odds are you were testing and everything was working fine, then you started testing with a white listed phone number, while doing so you were presented with captchas which got annoying so you found documented code to disable the captchas. Now, after weeks of testing with that you go back to production phone numbers only to find this error w/ not information on what's causing it. ;)

`[FIRAuth auth].settings.appVerificationDisabledForTesting = YES;`

^Set this back to NO and you'll be good to go!

Comment: in case of flutter, I've disabled it like this: `FirebaseAuth.instance.setSettings(appVerificationDisabledForTesting: false);`

Comment: Where should we do this disabling (in flutter that is)??

Comment: @ahmedtwabi Odds are you disabled it early on when you were first setting up the project and copy pasting code from firebase and you just forgot, that's what I had done. For Flutter, search your entire project for this `appVerificationDisabledForTesting`